# PHP Array not formatting correctly with JSON

Tags: php, arrays

I have generated a function that will go through my records within my database table and turn them into an array for further use

```
public function cycleCount()
{
    global $db;

    $selectProducts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stockroom_products");

    $results = array("catA", "catB", "catC");

    while($row = $db->assoc($selectProducts))
    {
        if($row['Product_PRICE'] >= 10)
        {
            array_push($results, "catA", $row['ID']);
        }
        else if ($row['Product_PRICE'] >= 5 AND $row['Product_PRICE'] < 10) 
        {
            array_push($results, "catB", $row['ID']);
        }
        else if ($row['Product_PRICE'] > 0 AND $row['Product_PRICE'] < 5)
        {
            array_push($results, "catC", $row['ID']);
        }


        $json_data = json_encode($results);
        //echo $json_data;

        echo $json_data;

    }

}
```

And I can't seem to figure out how to make the array like

```
[catC[ID1, ID2, ID3]], [catB[ID1, ID2, ID3]], [catA[ID1, ID2, ID3]]
```

at the moment it does this

```
["catA","catB","catC","catB","1"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14","catA","16"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14","catA","16","catB","17"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14","catA","16","catB","17","catA","18"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14","catA","16","catB","17","catA","18","catA","19"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14","catA","16","catB","17","catA","18","catA","19","catB","20"]["catA","catB","catC","catB","1","catC","2","catC","3","catC","4","catA","5","catC","6","catC","9","catA","10","catC","11","catC","12","catC","13","catA","14","catA","16","catB","17","catA","18","catA","19","catB","20","catB","21"]
```

Comment: I suppose `catC` (and `catA`) should be the keys?

Comment: Also you would do `json_encode` and `echo` after the `while`-loop, not inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing values to a string which doesn't work.

Try defining your result array like so:
`$result = array("catA" => array(), "catB" => array(), "catC" => array());`

This should get you nested arrays and thus the result you seek.
Also use `array_push($result['catA'], $row['ID']);` instead of `array_push($reuslt, 'catA', $row[ID'])`

And as @u_mulder correctly states the json should be echoed after the while loop!

Comment: Instead of `array_push`, you should use `[]` - much more readable

Comment: Also mention that echoing json should be done __after__ while-loop

Comment: @Philipp you can only use [] instead of array_push if you have a key and a value to go with it. Since this example only has a value you need to push it onto the array.

Comment: When I do this I end up with a white screen nothing is echoed

Comment: Are you encoding/echoing AFTER the while loop?

Comment: @Niels - you don't need a key! Ever tried `$data[] = ...`? - works like pushing a value at the end of `$data`

Comment: @Philipp aaah sorry I interpreted you remark differently. I tend not to use it since in my opinion it makes a push easier to miss when debugging. An empty array is easier to miss for me than array_push. But ofcourse to each their own!

Answer (score 0):

`array_push` does not key as second parameter according to the docs: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php

You should instead do it like this:

```
$results = array("catA" => [], "catB" => [], "catC" => []);
if($row['Product_PRICE'] >= 10)
{
    $results["catA"][] = $row['ID'];
}
else if ($row['Product_PRICE'] >= 5 AND $row['Product_PRICE'] < 10) 
{
    $results["catB"][] = $row['ID'];
}
else if ($row['Product_PRICE'] > 0 AND $row['Product_PRICE'] < 5)
{
    $results["catC"][] = $row['ID'];
}
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Also mention that echoing json should be done __after__ while-loop

Comment: When I move the echo after the while loop it shows only one record and when I do this above it echos this

{"catA":[],"catB":["1"],"catC":[]}{"catA":[],"catB":[],"catC":["2"]}{"catA":[],"catB":[],"catC":["3"]}{"catA":[],"catB":[],"catC":["4"]}{"catA":["5"],"catB":[],"catC":[]}{"catA":[],"catB":[],"catC":["6"]}

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Here's an example of my code: https://glot.io/snippets/evo86oyc8p

Comment: The `foreach` simulates what your `while` loop is doing

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
      piblic  function cycleCount(){
    global $db;

    $selectProducts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stockroom_products");
    $catA =array();
    $catB =array();
    $catC =array();
    $results = array();

    while($row = $db->assoc($selectProducts))
    {
        if($row['Product_PRICE'] >= 10)
        {
             array_push($catA,array('catA' =>$row['ID']));
        }
        else if ($row['Product_PRICE'] >= 5 AND $row['Product_PRICE'] < 10) 
        {
            array_push($catB,array('catB' =>$row['ID']));

        }
        else if ($row['Product_PRICE'] > 0 AND $row['Product_PRICE'] < 5)
        {

            array_push($catC,array('catC' =>$row['ID']));

        }


        $json_data = json_encode($results);
        //echo $json_data;

        echo $json_data;

    }
    $results=array($catA,$catB,$catC);
    print_r($results);
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\assets\system\classes\functions.php on line 19

this is the line:

array_push($catA, "catA"=> $row['ID']);